# How can I find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point $(-3,f(-3))$?

Tags: calculus

**Let f(t)=2/(t+8)**

(a) Simplify the following difference quotient as much as possible:
$$[f(t+h)−f(t)]/h$$

**MY ANSWER (CORRECT)**: $-2 / [(t+8)(t+h+8)]$

(b) Use your result from (a) and the limit definition of the derivative to calculate $f′(t)=\lim_{h → 0} [f(t+h)−f(t)]/h=$

**MY ANSWER (CORRECT)**: $-2 / [(t+8)^2]$

(c) Use your answer from part (b) to evaluate $f′(−3)$

**MY ANSWER (CORRECT)**: $-2 / 25$

(d) Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point $(−3,f(−3))$
y=

I have tried the point-slope formula, $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, but my answer was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Correct idea, Note that $x_1=-3$ and $y_1 = f(-3) = 22/3$, and by definition of derivative, the slope is given by $$m = f'(-3) = -2/25$$ from previous calculations, so the equation is $$
y - \frac{22}{3} = \frac{-2}{25}(x+3)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y = f'(3) t + b = - \frac{2}{25} t  + b$$
But $(-3,-\frac{2}{3} + 8) = (-3,\frac{22}{3})$ is a point on the line so
so
$$b = \frac{22}{3} - \frac{6}{25}$$
Hence
$$y  = - \frac{2}{25} t  +\frac{22}{3} - \frac{6}{25} = - \frac{2}{25} t +  \frac{532}{75} $$